# How to encode Greek letters on RSS feed using android studio

Tags: java, android, rss

So i want to use RSS FEED with android studio on a greek site.I used [this](https://www.journaldev.com/20126/android-rss-feed-app?fbclid=IwAR3_oiXPKqoJeh4v7LRvNABZ81IoO8vxmxi1hCWL4kdiFauAc1e2YX_H5pc) code and everything works good but the greek letters on the site are not recognised.Any help?[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag6C0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try **okhttp** instead of **apache**.

> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1"
}
```

> ResponseInterceptor.java

```
public class ResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        Response modifiedResponse =
                response.networkResponse().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .build();
        return modifiedResponse;
    }
}
```

Using

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .......
            .addInterceptor(new ResponseInterceptor())
            .build();
```